# FFmpeg performance on android devices

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm trying to make an app for android via Unity3D game engine which will basically 
be a video player.
I decide to use FFmpeg library which i linked to my C++ plugin using Android NDK.
I'm trying to play at least HD video and i stuck on performance problem.
Retrieving each frame of HD resolution takes near than 40 milliseconds of time. 1000 / 40 = 25 fps which is already not good enough because i did n`t even wrote audio handling yet. But how about full hd videos? Another video players on my device somehow playing full hd videos but i don't even know how they do.

Comment: Have you tried Exoplayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: No, but seems i need a C++ library like FFmpeg. Also, to try some new library i need to be sure at least that ffmpeg can't do what i need (cuzz i already overcome a lot of obstacles to at least set it up) and that a new one is definitely can.